# Creating a library for ASP.NET Core, but using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a library for ASP.NET Core in VS17 that uses System.Data.SqlClient for accesing database. I picked .NET Core Library Class. 
The problem is that I'm getting errors like :

> *CS0012    The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not >referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

On stackoverflow I found a thread with advice to add NuGet package : Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility, but then it just throws following exception :

> *FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, >Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

I tried getting other library types like .NET Standard or .NET Framework, but I am also getting errors e.g. some types from standard System.Data.SqlClient are unavailable.

**Is there a way to create a library for ASP.NET Core that uses SqlClient for accesing database then?**

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444487/how-to-use-sqlclient-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Well, you went off into the weeds.  SqlClient is included in .net core.  You are, for some unknown reasons, referencing the .net framework version.

Comment: I tried to do it this way : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/66489a/creating-C-Sharp-class-library-dll-using-visual-studio-2015-pre/
But it turned quite more complicated as I got more than one type of library to choose from. I've been using SqlClient in my previous Net Core apps, thats why I was amazed at getting those errors, while trying to place some methods in separate library

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of your.
Try simply run `dotnet restore myProjectName` on package manager console or on command prompt.

In this way the packages and SDK's on your project are download and reference problems will go away.