# How to connect MySQL DB on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, mysql, macos, .net-core

I have already tried to add SQLClient reference

```
using System.Data.SqlClient
```

But still I got these errors

I have been using macOS

[image: It]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444487/how-to-use-sqlclient-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SqlClient in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444487/how-to-use-sqlclient-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the `solutionExplorer`, go to `references`, right click on it and choose `add reference`. Now browse for the assembly `SqlClient` and hit the ok button.

---

But using the `using` statement in your code just saves you some additional words in order to shorten and simplify your code. Imagine if you would have added a reference of the assembly `System.Data.SqlClient` to your project, but didn't write `using System.Data.SqlClient;`, then you could still create a new `SqlConnection` object, but you have to add like an *address*, which assembly shell be used.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
```

But importing the reference needs to be done manual, a few basic assembly references have already been added by default, that's why

```
using System.Web.Mcv;
```

knows which referenced assembly is meant. For clarification, have a look at the referenced assemblies in your project and you will find `System.Web.Mcv` there, so it has been added there already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL.Data dll via nuget manager

[image]

After that use it as usual,

[image]