# .net core website reference a .net 4.6 library wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I keep getting a error in my .net core app. My .net core app does not reference Entity Framework but a 4.6 dll that it references does.

> The specified invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' wasn't found in
>   the list of registered .NET Data Providers.'

How do I add this data provider to the list in a .net core app ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use SqlClient in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444487/how-to-use-sqlclient-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Sorry this above post is dealing with 1.0 sounds like alot changed in 1.1 on the project.json file being deprecated